# Python + Django page redirect

Tags: python, django, redirect, location

How do I accomplish a simple redirect (e.g. `cflocation` in ColdFusion, or `header(location:http://)` for PHP) in Django?

Answer (score 256, accepted):

It's simple:

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

def myview(request):
    ...
    return HttpResponseRedirect("/path/")
```

More info in the [official Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponseRedirect)

**Update: Django 1.0**

There is apparently a better way of doing this in Django now using `generic views`.

Example -

```
from django.views.generic.simple import redirect_to

urlpatterns = patterns('',   
    (r'^one/$', redirect_to, {'url': '/another/'}),

    #etc...
)
```

There is more in the [generic views documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/generic-views/#django-views-generic-simple-redirect-to).
Credit - [Carles Barrobés](https://stackoverflow.com/users/166761/carles-barrobes).

**Update #2: Django 1.3+**

In Django 1.5 *redirect_to* no longer exists and has been replaced by [RedirectView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/class-based-views/base/#redirectview). Credit to [Yonatan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/221917/yonatan)

```
from django.views.generic import RedirectView

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^one/$', RedirectView.as_view(url='/another/')),
)
```

Comment: This is no longer the best method as of Django 1.0. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/523356/python-django-page-redirect/3841632#3841632

Comment: Why not using `redirect` from `django.shortcuts`?

Comment: I use `('^pattern/$', lambda x: redirect('/redirect/url/'))`

Comment: This is already deprecated starting in Django 1.5. Use 'RedirectView' instead: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/class-based-views/base/#redirectview

Comment: Its actually not deprecated, what are you saying is deprecated? redirect ?  Using this method I don't know how to pass the value of parameters to lambda, i.e. url(r'^(?P<location_id>\d+)/$', lambda x: HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('dailyreport_location', args=['%(location_id)', ]))) does not work

Answer (score 114):

Depending on what you want (i.e. if you do not want to do any additional pre-processing), it is simpler to just use Django's `redirect_to` generic view:

```
from django.views.generic.simple import redirect_to

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^one/$', redirect_to, {'url': '/another/'}),

    #etc...
)
```

See [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/generic-views/#django-views-generic-simple-redirect-to) for more advanced examples.

---

For Django 1.3+ use:

```
from django.views.generic import RedirectView

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^one/$', RedirectView.as_view(url='/another/')),
)
```

Comment: +1 for using a generic view rather than implementing your own (no matter how simple) as in the (current) top voted answer.

Comment: Does anyone have any examples for if you *do* want to do additional pre-processing?

Comment: Then I'd suggest either write a custom view that does the processing and then calls the generic view, or write a decorator e.g. pre_process and decorate the generic view: (r'^one/$', pre_process(redirect_to), {'url': '/another/'})

Comment: @niallsco: if you want to do additional processing, then it's best to use the redirect shortcut as described by Kennu in [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/523356/python-django-page-redirect/3645846#3645846)

Comment: In django 1.4, importing redirect_to gives a depracation warning.

Answer (score 38):

There's actually a simpler way than having a view for each redirect - you can do it *directly* in `urls.py`:

```
from django.http import HttpResponsePermanentRedirect

urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',
    # ...normal patterns here...
    (r'^bad-old-link\.php',
     lambda request: HttpResponsePermanentRedirect('/nice-link')),
)
```

[A target can be a callable as well as a string](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.0/topics/http/urls/#passing-callable-objects-instead-of-strings), which is what I'm using here.

Comment: True, but using the `redirect_to` generic view that comes with django is simpler still and more readable. See Carles answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/523356/python-django-page-redirect/3841632#3841632

Answer (score 28):

Since Django 1.1, you can also use the simpler [redirect](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect) shortcut:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def myview(request):
    return redirect('/path')
```

It also takes an optional permanent=True keyword argument.

Answer (score 14):

If you want to redirect a whole subfolder, the `url` argument in [RedirectView is actually interpolated](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/class-based-views/base/#redirectview), so you can do something like this in `urls.py`:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import url
from django.views.generic import RedirectView

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^old/(?P<path>.*)$', RedirectView.as_view(url='/new_path/%(path)s')),
]
```

---

The `?P<path>` you capture will be fed into `RedirectView`.  This captured variable will then be replaced in the `url` argument you gave, giving us `/new_path/yay/mypath` if your original path was `/old/yay/mypath`.

You can also do `….as_view(url='…', query_string=True)` if you want to copy the query string over as well.

Answer (score 10):

With Django version 1.3, the class based approach is:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, url
from django.views.generic import RedirectView

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^some-url/$', RedirectView.as_view(url='/redirect-url/'), name='some_redirect'),
)
```

This example lives in in urls.py

Answer (score 6):

Beware.  I did this on a development server and wanted to change it later.

- [Firefox 5 'caching' 301 redirects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6980192/firefox-5-caching-301-redirects)

I had to clear my caches to change it.  In order to avoid this head-scratching in the future, I was able to make it temporary like so:

```
from django.views.generic import RedirectView

url(r'^source$', RedirectView.as_view(permanent=False, 
                                      url='/dest/')),
```

Answer (score 2):

page_path = define in urls.py

```
def deletePolls(request):
    pollId = deletePool(request.GET['id'])
    return HttpResponseRedirect("/page_path/")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in the Admin section. It's explained in the documentation.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/redirects/

Comment: While not quite pertinent to my question, this is still an interesting piece of information.

Answer (score 0):

This should work in most versions of django, I am using it in 1.6.5:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ....
    url(r'^(?P<location_id>\d+)/$', lambda x, location_id: HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('dailyreport_location', args=[location_id])), name='location_stats_redirect'),
    ....
)
```

You can still use the name of the url pattern instead of a hard coded url with this solution.  The location_id parameter from the url is passed down to the lambda function.