# django redirecting '/' to a flat page

Tags: python, django, routes

I'm trying to get `'/'` to redirect to `'/first-page'` where `'/first-page'` is a built-in flat page with the slug first-page

I'm looking for something like

```
(r'^/', 'redirect_to', {'url': '/flat-page'}),
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python + Django page redirect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/523356/python-django-page-redirect)

Comment: @jleedev: it is a duplicate, but the "best" answer has changed since then with the introduction of the `redirect_to` generic view.

Comment: @Chris, `redirect_to` was in Django 1.0 (http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.0/ref/generic-views/#django-views-generic-simple-redirect-to) which existed before that top voted answer on the possible duplicate. Tssk. Let's upvote the `redirect_to` answer over there to fix this travesty http://stackoverflow.com/questions/523356/python-django-page-redirect/3841632#3841632 ;)

Comment: @Day: not checking my sources again... *sigh* :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Django's generic views

```
urlpatterns = patterns('django.views.generic.simple',
    ('^$', 'redirect_to', {'url': '/first-page'}),
)
urlpatterns += patterns('myProject.myApp',
    ...
)
```

or

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ('^$', 'django.views.generic.simple.redirect_to', {'url': '/first-page'}),
    ...
)
```

See [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/generic-views/#django-views-generic-simple-redirect-to) for more info and examples.

Watch your URL matching too, that one you have will match anything starting with /. Like example.com//anything, note the double slash.

Comment: +1 for `django.views.generic.simple.redirect_to`, +1 for `'^$'` instead of `'^/'` which will match everything and so would need to go last and would break 404s.

Comment: Thanks @Chris, am I right that `r'^/'` would match `example.com//anything` but not `example.com/anything` ? I haven't tested that.  -- Update: tested and correct.

Answer (score 1):

Inside the view for the url, you can use `HttpResponseRedirect`.

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

def rootview(request):
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/flat-page')
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`HttpResponsePermanentRedirect`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponsePermanentRedirect):

```
from django.http import HttpResponsePermanentRedirect
# ...
(r'^$', 'redirect_to', lambda request: HttpResponsePermanentRedirect('/flat-page')),
```

Comment: I don't think that will even work. If you insist on using a lambda function do this: `(r'^$', lambda request: HttpResponsePermanentRedirect('/flat-page'))`

Comment: You're right. I took the code from the question, which I assumed to be correct.