# Hybrid Auth - "This page cannot be accessed directly" error

Tags: facebook-graph-api, hybridauthprovider

Talking about **[Hybid Auth](http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/)**, I'm using **Facebook** to login the users, but I don't know what did I modify in the code that is causing the system to show the **"Sorry, This page cannot be accessed directly"** message.

I see it's related with the **$_SESSION["HA::CONFIG"]** variable when the system is checking **if Hybrid_Auth session already exist** in the file **hybridauth/hybridauth/index.php**

Could you let me know how can I fix this?

Comment: Apparently is because it's in an iframe.

Comment: I also had an iframe but removed it, still have the same problem though, only in firefox

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm using HybridAuth 2.0.11 Installer
While you are installing Hybrid Auth via the /hybridauth/install.php
ensure that the HybridAuth Endpoint URL
contains the url in the format
http://domain.com & not http://www.domain.com or some other subdomain
Also verify that the you have the same format of the url mentioned in your facebook twitter linkedin developer accounts.

Comment: Also having www in the page url you're trying to test on spanners it as well.

Comment: Seems a bit illogical.. what if you only have the www domain? I've experienced that scenario once.. and what if the user has entered www.domain.com doesn't it work then?? :S

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this issue when trying to sign in using `Firefox` and although `hybridauth` was working great on all browsers, it was failing on Firefox browsers. so if you are looking for an answer to

> hybridauth firefox You cannot access this page directly

here is the solution.

the problem is that `Firefox` has a caching mechanism for page redirects, you can find out more about this topic on this thread [firefox-5-caching-301-redirects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6980192/firefox-5-caching-301-redirects)

as a result, if you are trying to authenticate a user on a `login page` and the cache headers for that page were in the range of 30x (301-302-303-304...) firefox is more likely to cache that page on the client side.

So when a user tries to sign in, the`login page` will not be processed on your server, instead `firefox` will serve a cached version of the `login page` which redirects to the `hybridauth` authentication page, failing in turn to initialize the `Session Object` required for authentication.

Solution: turn off the `caching headers` for the `login page` and make sure that it returns a `200` code

Answer (score 0):

My Facebook App was in Sandbox mode, **disable Sandbox** fixed it for me!!

Answer (score 0):

Use $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] in the endpoint URL when configuring HybridAuth