# Login Required Middleware gets HTTP/1.1" 302

Tags: django, authentication, middleware

I've done a simple login that works fine while the authenticated user is redirected to a page with url:

```
url(r'^(?P<user_id>\d+)/$', 'auth.views.main', name='main'),
```

Now I'm trying to use a `LoginRequired-Middleware` but when I do and I try to login I get:

```
"POST  /login/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
"GET   /1000/  HTTP/1.1" 302 0
```

and I remain to the initial login-page.
I use a common [snippet](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1179/) for doing that with

`LOGIN_URL = ( '/login/' )`

What's going wrong?

Comment: what is your entry for `r'^login/$'` in urls.py?

Comment: (r'^login/$', 'auth.views.login_user')

Comment: What is this "login required middleware"?

Comment: it's a @login_required decorator for all the views of my site. It requires only authenticated users to have access to the entire app

Comment: Can you verify you don't have an additional decorator on your view and/or post the view's code?

Comment: It doesn't even work with a simple @login_required(login_url='/login/') for the view main. Maybe it's my login code that causes the prob?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately your provided code is insufficient to determine your error, so I can only give you pointers:

- Make sure you aren't actually still caching an HTTP 302 REDIRECT site, from earlier experimenting. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6980192/firefox-5-caching-301-redirects) for useful hints.
  Reset your browser-cache. If you are using Chrome, you can get several cache clearance options by pressing CTRL+SHIFT+J (starting the Developer Tools), and long pressing the Reload button next to the top navigation url-bar.

  For Firefox, see also these useful suggestions.

  1. http://support.mozilla.org/es/questions/848678
  2. https://superuser.com/questions/23134/how-to-turn-off-firefox-cache
- Did you just upgrade Django from version <1.3.x? I came across a situation where passwords were rewritten with a new default-Hasher, and thus one could no longer log in. Check password-hasher consistency directly in your database, within the `auth_users` - table. For instance SHA1 password-hashes start with `sha1...`
- Make sure to setup the list `PASSWORD_HASHERS` in your `settings.py`, is in an order that retains the original project's *primary Hasher*  on top. i.e. the hashing-algorithm that was used to initially hash the user passwords.
- Is the `url(r'...'...)` in the root `urls.py` of your project?
- Make sure `'django.contrib.auth'` is listed in your `INSTALLED_APPS` section of `settings.py` (though you should get error's if that is not the case) and apps that must be loaded beforehand, are actually placed uppermost.
- Check the setup of your `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`, `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` in settings.py according to your snippet's comments and make sure it is compatible with the `SessionMiddleware` of your Django version.
- Check all codelines in your project that make redirects:

Check for:

```
    from django.views.generic.base import RedirectView

    url(r'^.*$', RedirectView.as_view(url='<url_to_view>', permanent=False), name='index')
```

or

```
    from django.http import HttpResponsePermanentRedirect
    HttpResponsePermanentRedirect('url...')
```

Note that in Django 1.5 the deprecated `redirect_to` function has been replaced by `RedirectView`, according to their generic view paradigm.

[redirect(...)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect)

```
    url('^pattern/$', lambda _: redirect('/redirecttourl/'))
    url(r'^pattern$', redirect('example.com')),
    url(r'^pattern$', redirect(projectname.views.home)),
    (r'^accounts/profile/$', 'redirect_to', {'url': 'generic_account_url'}),
    HttpResponseRedirect(....)
    HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER','/'))
```

- Django's built-in authentication login page includes a `next` query string. `next=` determines the the page to return to after login:

See: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.login_required

- Check your server's HTTP access logs. Is the content-size of the login-site after the redirect the same as the login before the redirect?

It helps providing the entire HTTP access history during the login process. As you do not hang in an redirect-loop, more HTTP's than the two mentioned must follow.