# Fiddler shows clicking link to a page sends request to another page instead

Tags: html, asp.net, caching, redirect

A weird thing has been happening in my ASP.NET website. There is an `asp:HyperLink` on the ASPX page whose `NavigateURL` is set to the page Portal.aspx. The page gets rendered correctly, the link gets rendered as `<a href = 'Portal.aspx'...`

The weird thing is that when in Firefox I click the link that is supposed to take me to the page Portal.aspx, I get redirected to another page (the website's error page). I checked everything as I suspected an exception was sending me off to that page and to my surprise, no server side code ever gets executed when the link is clicked.

I asked Fiddler what was going on, and it seems that when I click the link to Portal.aspx, Firefox is asking the server for Error.aspx.

Anyone knows why is Firefox behaving this way? Is caching responsible for any part of this? How do I tell Firefox to request Portal.aspx and not the wrong page?

EDIT: I know the page is there, and it works fine for some time. There is no error anywhere because no server-side code even gets executed. But if the session expires and that page displays an error once, from then on - according to Fiddler - Firefox *won't even ask for* Portal.aspx. Clicking the links sends a request with URL 'Error.aspx" to server. I am convinced this is a caching issue.

Comment: Turn off Custom Errors and find out what the error is on that page. It almost sounds like that page doesn't exist.

Comment: or like it is in another directory. There is no `<base href>` element on the page?

Comment: Most likely it's a [caching issue](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6980192/8655), while you're debugging there are some [temporary workarounds](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/848678).

Comment: It was a caching issue.