# how to solve "301 Moved Permanently " status issue in mozilla firefox for redirection of url

Tags: http-status-code-301, http-status-codes

Redirection url opens up in google chrome without any issue but shows status of "301 Moved Permanently" in firefox(firebug). How am i to solve this issue?

Any help/suggestion is welcome.

Comment: You mean in the browser's body it shows **301 Moved Permanently** ?

Comment: @armnotstrong no in firebug ..

Comment: I think there may be something related to the caching in the firefox, check [this issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6980192/firefox-5-caching-301-redirects) and see if you can find some idea there.