# Can a subdomain be set up to force a client side browser to refresh their cache?

Tags: redirect, dns, bluehost

**Situation:**  I have a generic subdomain tickets.nsuf.org that I want to use every year to direct customers to the correct page on a 3rd party website to buy tickets for the current year.  (The ticket service we use changes their URL for each event and it is long)

**Problem:**  If I have a customer that used the subdomain last year, the old URL is stored in their browser history or cache, so when they try to use it for this years event, it directs them to the wrong page on the ticket service website and looks like our event is closed.

**Question:**  Is there a way that I can set up the subdomain / redirect to force the client side browser to update the cache / history files and go to the new page?

**Just to clarify:**  I have the subdomain and redirect to the correct page on the ticket service working fine, but only if the end user didn't use it last year.

Screenshot of the way the redirect is set up on BlueHost:

[image]

**Things I have Tried:**

1. I changed from a 301 to a 302 Redirect.  Not seeing any difference
   within 15 minutes of changing.  Haven't tested waiting a day yet.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it because you use permanent redirect (301) instead of a temporary one (302)?

Comment: I just removed the 301 version and created a new one with a 302.  So far I don't see any difference in the browsers that I haven't cleared history on.  Is that a change that takes effect quickly or do I need to wait a day to see results?

Comment: I would expect that once you changed 301 to 302, you would still need to clear the redirect cache (https://stackoverflow.com/a/12796598/8019153). But next change of ticket service URL wouldn't require such action.

Answer (score -1):

I don't see what the problem is. User cache is invalidated after a very short period of time.

As long as you set up your site to redirect the user to the correct page, that is what they will see. A user cannot manually go into their caches and navigate to an old URL

Comment: Last year, the subdomain was redirected to https://one.bidpal.net/2022wfns.  I updated for this years event which is https://one.bidpal.net/2023wfns.  I tried 3 different browsers and they all went to the old page.  (I even waited a day and tried again.  same thing)  As soon as I clear, the history and cache files from one of the browsers the redirect works as it should on that browser and goes to the link for 2023.  The other two browsers still go to the old webpage, so it has to be something involved in those history / cache files in my mind

Comment: Share the code in question – maybe that can help us

Comment: I don't have any code.  It is a redirect on the BlueHost web hosting platform.  Let me see if I can screen shot and add it to my post or something.