# Django admin urlpatterns redirect_to

Tags: django, admin, url-pattern

I have a view that has a decorator which redirects to admin login page as following

> @login_required(login_url='/admin')

That means whenever a user tries to access /admin/some/url/ he will be asked to login through admin page at /admin/?next=/admin/some/url/

My question is: how do I handle redirecting after the user has logged in via the admin page?

> /admin/?next=/admin/some/url/ -> /admin/some/url/

I assume that I need to tweak my app's urlpatterns and use **redirect_to** from

> django.views.generic.simple

and overwrite

> (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls))

P.S: To simplify this question: I need a regex to match /admin/some/url/ in /admin/?next=/admin/some/url/ so I can use it for my redirect_to function

Comment: Does this answer your question? [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/523356/python-django-page-redirect][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/523356/python-django-page-redirect

Comment: Er, why? What does this have to do with regexes?

Comment: @DanielRoseman what I meant was to use regex to match whatever is after /admin/?next= and redirect_to the matched value. Unless you have a better option?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend to not use the admin stuff to manage user authentication.

See [the Django documentation about Authentication Views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/#module-django.contrib.auth.views), this is really easy and automatically does the right thing with the `next` parameter.

Probably this didn't exist yet when you asked the question nine years ago :-)