# How to use an action in a form, but still ultimately redirect to the original URL, as smoothly as possible

Tags: django, forms, url, redirect

I'm using Django but being crazy and submitting forms with Javascript and stuff.

I have a form that has an action that's only there because I couldn't get it to process the data I wanted correctly (that is, I'm using the action URL to redirect to two different parts of a view that each do what I want). It's working great, except after using the forms I see the URL `www.example.com/formone` and `www.example.com/formtwo` after pressing each. Due to the way it's setup it looks just like `www.example.com`, except for the URL. Also if you reload the page without the `POST` data, using the same URL, it fails, because I only process post data from those URLs.

Is there a way to redirect at the end of the `view`?

For example, something like:

```
def formone(request):
...
...
return render(request, 'example.html', 'www.example.com', {
         'formone': form, 'formtwo': voteform, 'items': items
            })
```

where `www.example.com` is the redirect URL, would be desirable. I can probably do this in Javascript on the actual page, but that seems even more sketchy.

Comment: I am not sure if I am following. It would probably be better if you can provide the relevant parts from the urls.py and views.py.

Comment: Can you just use [the redirect shortcut](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect) at the end of your view?

Comment: Ok, you should post that as an answer though! I'm trying the above solution, will add more details if it doesn't work.

Comment: I wasn't sure if I understood the question, so put it in as a comment instand of answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [the redirect shortcut](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect) at the end of your view.

Comment: Yeah, I think this should work fine (sorry SE community for not researching more first). For some reason my view is saying "Import by filename not supported" though, and interpreting my URL as a filepath... shouldn't be too hard to fix.

Answer (score 0):

I actually used HTTPResponseRedirect, because the redirect shortcut wouldn't accept a URL and was expecting a filepath for some reason.

Evidently there are a few ways to do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523356/python-django-page-redirect) (tsk, tsk Django, not following the Python language principle so well). Haha, I'm happy something's working though!

Comment: [django.shortcuts.redirect source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.4.1/django/shortcuts/__init__.py#L47) indicates that it works with a url as argument. "tsk, tsk Django, not following the Python language principle so well" could you elaborate ?

Comment: Apparently there are a few options for redirecting from within a view, is all I'm saying; namely `rediret`, `HTTPResponseRedirect`, and possibly some methods involving "generic views", which I don't quite understand, as they appear to be very similar to what's in the url.py file. 
I love Python, and Django!

Comment: Whoops, submitted that early, but `redirect` and `HTTPResponseRedirect` both take a filepath or a URL, so it seems repetitive, and I thought one of the principles of Python is that there should be only one way to do something in particular, and furthermore it should be obvious. With `response` it is obvious.

Comment: I'm sorry, I've been using Django for years and I don't understand what you are talking about. I have never had to repeat a URL **ever** in Django. Maybe there's something wrong with your explanations ? Also, did you read the source code of `django.shortcuts.redirect` that I linked in my previous comment ? You can pass a model, url name, or a url string - that should have been reversed manually with `django.core.urlresolvers.reverse`, and it will make an `django.http.HTTPResponseRedirect` or `django.http.HTTPResponsePermanentRedirect` that the view can return. I wonder what "filepath" is.

Comment: ok, sorry for bad-mouthing Django, I'm a newb; I was referring to this part of "the zen of python" [There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)

And that there are a few different ways of redirecting. I used `HTTPResponeRedirect`. Evidently using simply `redirect` works for most people (or at least you two). For me, it did not. I wish I knew why it was talking about a file path or filepath or whatever too, but I don't, I simply know that `redirect` did not work for me, and the above solution did. So I'm happy.

Comment: Well obviously, django.shortcuts.redirect is a shortcut to create an HttpResponseRedirect - or HttpResponsePermanentRedirect. The zen of Python doesn't have anything against django.shortcuts, which are mainly factories.