# How to redirect (including URL change) in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls

I have created an `index.html`. I want this page (or the `view`) to be shown when somebody goes to `http://www.mypage.com/` and `http://www.mypage.com/index/`. Since I'm new to `Django`, this could be a bad way:
In my **URLS.PY:**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$',views.index),
    url(r'^index/$',views.index),...
    ...
```

This works properly but I'm curious, whether is it possible to change the `url` from `http://www.mypage.com/` to `http://www.mypage.com/index/` when somebody goes to `http://www.mypage.com/`.

I've already tried change this:

```
url(r'^$',views.index),
```

to this:

```
url(r'^$','/index/'),
```

but it raises error:

```
Could not import '/index/'. The path must be fully qualified.
```

Could somebody give me an advice how to do that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want to do it via code it is:

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

def frontpage(request):
    ...
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/index/')
```

But you can also do it directly in the urls rules:

```
from django.views.generic import RedirectView

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^$', RedirectView.as_view(url='/index/')),
)
```

For reference, see this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/523366/5770129

Comment: If you are using Django < 1.9, you probably want `RedirectView.as_view(url='/index/', permanent=False)`, because it defaults to a permanent redirect until Django 1.9.

Comment: It would be slightly better to use `pattern_name='index'`, rather than `url='/index/'`, to avoid hardcoding the url.

Answer (score 3):

What you could do, is the following. Put this in your urls.py:

```
url(r'^$',views.redirect_index),
```

and in your views:

```
def redirect_index(request):
    return redirect('index')
```

Comment: Which is the RightWay to solve the problem - you don't want to have two distinct urls serving the same content (unless you don't care about SEO that is).