# How to create a registration form in Django that is divided into two parts, such that one call fill up the second part only after email verification?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-authentication

I have the logic for email verification, but I am not sure how to make it such that only after clicking the link on the verification email, the user is taken to the second page of the form, and only after filling the second part the user is saved.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python + Django page redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523356/python-django-page-redirect)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that much better idea is to save user to database anyway, but mark him as inactive (simple boolean field in model will be enough). Upon registration, before confirming email mark him as inactive and as soon as he confirms email and fills second part of your registration form that you mentioned change that boolean value to true. If you don't want to keep inactive users data in your database, you can set up for example cron, that will clean users that haven't confirmed their email for few days.

Answer (score 0):

Visit the URL. I hope you get your answers. This appears to be duplicate of the below question asked on Stackoverflow itself
[Check this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523356/python-django-page-redirect)