# Redirect urls in django

Tags: django, django-urls

We have a blog created with Django 4. And have articles where for each article exists a url like this

```
www.example.com/id/slug
```

but for some of them we changed the id and we want to redirect the old urls to the new one.
For example we want to turn

```
www.example.com/2/slug1
```

to

```
www.example.com/56/slug1
```

And this is the urls.py content:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('<pk>/<custom_slug:persian_slug>/', 
        views.post_detail, name='post_detail'),
]
```

And here is views.py content:

```
def post_detail(request, pk, persian_slug):
    template_file = 'posts/post/post.html'
    post = get_object_or_404(Magazine, id=pk)
    latest_posts = Magazine.objects.filter(enable=1).filter(service_id__in=[29, 48, 58, 78]).\
        order_by('-created').using('default')[:3]

    subject = ''
    name = ''
    service_id = post.service_id

    context = {'post': post, 'latest_posts': latest_posts, 'subject': subject, 'name': name}

    return render(request, template_file, context)
```

How can we do this in Django 4?

Comment: Show your code: urls.py, views.py

Comment: Which views and url patterns your abstract url examples should belong?

Comment: I don't undrestand what you mean, can you explain more?

Comment: Are those url examples supposed to be handled by `post_detail` url pattern? `www.example.com/56/slug1` - is this `post_detail` url? If so please remove all the not related code from your question: two other views which have nothing to do with your question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python + Django page redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523356/python-django-page-redirect)

Comment: I saw it but is it work. Or it is deprecated in Django 4?

Comment: How will Django know the old ids?